# AFrame gltf loader not recognizing my assets

Tags: webpack, vue.js, aframe

## vue+webpack+aframe started well

Hi! I'm trying to use vuejs to construct a scene which includes a gltf model.

My project is setup using vue cli with webpack template.

For basic setup, as you can see, it's working as expected.

[image]

### Here's the not happy part.

For default setup, webpack won't let me require gltf/glb file.
Therefore I have installed and used file-loader to bake it into static.

This is the part I changed in webpack.config.js.

```
{
        test: /\.(glb)(\?.*)?$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {}
        }]
},
```

And in the .vue file, I've used vue to dynamically load it.

```
  data () {
    return {
      img: require('../assets/NormalTangentTest.glb')
    }
  }
```

Finally, for html, I've used the syntax from [Aframe 0.7 doc](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/components/gltf-model.html#sidebar), and use v:bind to bind src to my local assets.

```
<a-scene>
  <a-assets>
    <a-asset-item id="tree" :src="img')"></a-asset-item>
  </a-assets>
  <a-entity gltf-model="#tree"></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

This is what I got with both npm dev server and python http.server.

[image]

The gltf file is indeed baked and loaded.
But in the console, it says assets not found.

[image]

---

Questions:

1. How can I get webpack to pack the right files?
2. Is there better way to load gltf and it's depending textures with file loader?
3. For vue/webpack setup, what is the best way to handle assets management in aframe?
4. Should I just host the static file with nginx or use absolute path to link the folder I put the gltf files in?

Thx for your patience.

Comment: I can solve this with putting files in the static folder, but that will prevent webpack from picking the only needed one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first drop the GLTF file [here.](https://glb-packer.glitch.me/)

I have a slightly more detailed process [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59187115/12282360) which goes over each step, but this would allow the file to be packed.