# How do you properly load a GTLF file in A-Frame (Specifically in glitch?)

Tags: html, google-chrome, aframe

I downloaded a 3d model in .gltf from a website like sketchfab. If I drag the compressed .zip file into my assets folder and get a link that a-frame can use for it, it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to

### 1 Extract your zip file.

Extract your zip file by right clicking on it in file explorer and pressing "extract all"

### 2 Open the new folder

Now that you have extracted your .gltf file, you should automatically be brought either 2 or 3 files. They may be `textures` `scene` and `scene.bin` [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WHKFjQ7jGJA) video has a great description of the differences in these, and a detailed explanation on this entire process.

### 3 Highlight all these files and drop them to https://glb-packer.glitch.me/

This website will put them all into `out.glb` and this is the file you can upload to your assets.

Reference the 3d model as

```
<a-gltf-model></a-gltf-model>
```

and add the link from your assets with the `src` tag.